# What language(s) do the Minions speak?

Tags: minions, minions-movie

In the Minions movie, the Minions seem to speak bits and pieces of at least English and Italian (I think). For example, when counting, they count, 'uno, duo, tree'.  When they wanted to know what was going on, they would ask, 'que paso'. And, of course, English words like 'boss' were scattered throughout.  I didn't understand most of what they were saying, but this leads me to wonder what language(s) they were speaking.

**What language, or mash up of languages, did the Minions speak?**

Comment: "*Some of the words are from other foreign languages like Spanish, Korean, Chinese and Filipino.*"; http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Beckoliver.marron/OFFICIAL:_English_to_Minion_Language_Dictionary

Comment: Great catch!  That looks the start of an answer :-)

Comment: I for one don't understand the downvotes here… +1 from me. (As a corollary, or perhaps a different question altogether: if the Minions are so many millions of years old, how come their language, such as it is, seems to consist entirely of fragments of _modern-day_ languages from all around the world? And what did they speak before humans started developing their laryngeal and lingual muscles to accommodate speech?)

Comment: They speak Minionese. Various human cultures adopted words from their language over the millenia, not we from them :)

Comment: seriously +1 from me as well, seems to be a valid question. Why so much flurry of downvotes ??? do explain so that the OP can better himself / herself.

Comment: I imagine that the downvotes is that, on the surface, it seems like an unanswerable question other than "Minioneese" but, as the answers below show, there was actual thought in the language creation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is addressed on [this site](http://www.despicablememinions.net/despicable-me-minions/).

The Minions speak 'Minion-ese', which is described as being

> especially created for Despicable Me Minions? Some of the words are
>   derived from Spanish, Japanese and even Korean words.

Here is a [Minion-ese Dictionary](http://minionpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary) from which we see the following real languages are used:

- Korean (Dul)
- Italian (Gelato)
- Japanese (Kampai)
- Spanish (Para tu)
- Filipino (Pwede na)
- English (Banana)
- Russian ([Source](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Minionese))

EDIT

As pointed out by @b_jonas in the comments, German is also used when Kevin is thought to be dead

Comment: (Of course, _para tu_ is not proper Spanish—that would be _para ti_.)

Comment: Didn't one of the creators state in an interview that the language was largely based on French?

Comment: Nice answer, @N_Soong. +1

Comment: German is included as well.  When the minions think Kevin died, they clearly say "tot".

Answer (score 2):

There was definitely French in there...one of the minions says "la-bas..." (at one point in the film, when the minions split up in different directions). Interestingly enough, I also picked up a phrase in Bahasa Indonesia, when one of the minions responds "Terima Kasi" or "Thank you".

Answer (score -1):

They speak wide variety of languages mostly are the mixture of languages.

here is the language translated and origins.

http://www.fiz-x.com/minions-banana-language-translated/

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  This is what we call a 'link-only' answer; your answer's quality would be greatly improved if you extracted the information from the site you have linked to and detail this information in your answer, citing the website of course!